# JavaScript alert with label's text

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Quick and silly question perhaps, but how do I pass a label's text into a javascript confirm or alert function?

Here is what I've done but it's not good:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGVDeleteMessage" runat="server" Text="Show me!" style="display:none;" ></asp:Label>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete" 
    CommandName="Delete" Height="15px" ImageUrl="~/Images/document_delete.png" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('#<%=lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>')" 
    Width="15px" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: use return confirm(document.getElementById('#<%=lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>').innerHtml)"

Answer (score 3):

You need to grab the element by it's ID, then read it's `innerHTML` property:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm(document.getElementById('<%=lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>').innerHTML)"
```

But you might want to consider moving the logic out into another function:

Script:

```
function showConfirm(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    return confirm(elem.innerHTML);
}
```

ASPX:

```
OnClientClick="return showConfirm('<%=lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>')"
```

Comment: Thank you both for your fast reply, but I'm getting this error: 
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference
For both the innerText and InnerHTML properties. Perhaps I should add that the button and the label are inside a gridview's column, thus the ClientIDs will differ in the rendered HTML.

Comment: I did as you suggested above, but when I debug the JS function, the id is passed just like this: "<%=lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>" and therefore the elem is null. As I've said, both the button and the label are inside columns of a gridview and I'm also using a master page.

Comment: Try `<%#lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>` instead

Comment: Nothing seems to work :( I've tried even with other controls on the page that are not inside a gridview and I still can't seem to access them via JS..

Comment: Ok, I'm not happy about it but the only way I made it work was to set ClientIDMode="Static" on the label and on the OnClientClick event do this "return showConfirm('lblGVDeleteMessage');"

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this to be:

```
"return confirm(document.getElementById('#<%=lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>').innerHTML)"
```

---

Based off the comment below and the fact that you must be dynamically setting the text to the label in the first place, can you not just set the text dynamically into the call instead?  Bit neater than outputting an extra dom element that will always be hidden, e.g.:

```
"return confirm('<%# SomeFunctionTosetTheText() %>')"
```

Comment: You should use `textContent` and `innerText` as a fallback - `innerText` is proprietary IE

Comment: Tried that, it didn't worked. I get:  JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference For both the innerText and InnerHTML properties. Perhaps I should add that the button and the label are inside a gridview's column, thus the ClientIDs will differ in the rendered HTML. I created a function as @RGraham suggested below but the ID is passed as string as follows: "<%=lblGVDeleteMessage.ClientID%>"

Answer (score 0):

The only way I made it work was to set ClientIDMode="Static" on the label and on the OnClientClick event do this: "return showConfirm('lblGVDeleteMessage');"